# JdbcBatchItemWriter Error Parameter index out of range

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

There's an error on using Spring batch JdbcBatchItemWriter.

insert into books(order_id, order_no, paid_payment_id)  values (:orderId, :orderNo, :paidPaymentId)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfosv.png)

```
  private JdbcBatchItemWriter<BooksEntity> booksWriter() {
    return new JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder<BooksEntity>()
        .itemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<>())
        .dataSource(dataSource)
        .sql(
            "insert into books(order_id, order_no, paid_at, paid_payment_id, pay_method, pay_no, pg, service_type, status, transaction_amount, transaction_at, vat_amount, canceled_at, created_at) "
                + " values (:expectedCalculationAmount, :feeAmount, :orderId, :orderNo, :paidAt, :paidPaymentId, :payMethod, :payNo, pg, :serviceType, :status, :transactionAmount, :transactionAt, :vatAmount, :canceledAt, :createdAt)")
CalculationOriginalAccountBooksItemPreparedStatementSetter())
        .build();

  }
```

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/book?useSSL=false&useUnicode=true&serverTimezone=Asia/Seoul
    password: root
    username: root
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
  jpa:
    open-in-view: false
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
```

S1009 Error I don't know what that means.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I can notice right away is that you have used `pg` in the values instead of `:pg` which would get replaced during the query formation.

Comment: @myeongsasoo in other words you have less parameters than you have table columns because you forgot to precede `pg` with `:`. Refer to [Getting SQL error SQL State S1009](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44164234/getting-sql-error-sql-state-s1009). Note that in that question they are using question marks rather than actual parameter names (as you do) but the problem is still the same, i.e. there are less parameters than there are columns of the database table in the INSERT statement.

Comment: Precisely there are 14 columns listed in query but 16 values. 15 values are named parameters. 1 (pg) is probably just missing ':' Anyway - the numbers don't match and causes the error S1009.

Answer (score 0):

- Try after adding ':' before pg
- Check CalculationOriginalAccountBooksItemPreparedStatementSetter with all columns are mapped according to the query.
- Still it's not working means try by add NamedJdbcTemplate in writer